# Custom HTML select menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So as you know if you have a select, it stretches the container to accommodate the longest length option.

I have a truncate function that is basically a substr, length of 20, add periods to the end so it does not stretch it.

I have searched but either i am not searching right or it doesn't exist, but i want to be able to click on the select and it show the entire option OVER the page and not push the surrounding elements. A position fixed so to speak, except not because i dont want the page to scroll around the select.

Anyone know of any plugins or anything that do this?

EXAMPLE

This is a really...

This is done so it does not stretch the entire TD element it is in. Now when i click on the select to view the choices, i would like it to actually show

This is a really long sentence that was truncated.

HOWEVER i do not want it to push the TD cell's width when displaying it, so a hide/show of different select menus would not work, as that would push the width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is a stupid answer. But have you tried `position:absolute;`?
CSS does some wonderful tricks.

Also, the periods at the end of a sentence can be done wih css, using `white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden`.

Comment: Didn't use the position absolute, but style="white-space:nowrap; text-overflow:ellipsis; overflow:hidden; width:200px;" did the trick

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do it would be to convert the `<select>` to a [bootstrap dropdown](http://blog.iamjamoy.com/docs/select.html).

Comment: Thanks but that wouldn't do what i need... I will edit the question to add more detail.